# jquery widget, _create or _init

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, widget, construction

Some jquery plugin extend widget use _create method, while others use _init method, can someone explain the differences between the two?

Also any guidance on when it is better to extend widget or directly extend jquery.fn?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The downside to extending widget (as opposed to $.fn) is that you create a dependency on jquery-ui which defines the widget "class".  That dependency could be expensive for users of your plugin that don't also use jquery-ui.

As far as _create vs _init goes, I'm pretty sure that _init came first and then in a recent revision they introduced and favor _create.  I might be wrong about this, but I believe that _init is still supported.  If it is then there shouldn't be any differences between the two.

Comment: Good point on widget. Do you have any replacement of widget if I don't want to introduce additional dependency to jqueryui?

Comment: You could just rip out the widget code and include it in your .js file.  There was talk about moving widget into jquery itself instead of jqueryui but I don't know if that's been slated for a specific release or not yet.

Comment: There is a different between the _init and _create. _create is called only once. _init will be called multiple time as mentionned from @fudgey

Answer (score 18):

From the [jQuery UI Developer Guide](http://docs.jquery.com/UI_Developer_Guide):

> Once the element is created, all other calls to the widget name where the first parameter is not a string will call the _init() method; if options are passed, the .option() method will be called before the _init() method

Comment: Unfortunately, link is now toast.

Comment: [Try this link to the api](https://api.jqueryui.com/jquery.widget/#method-_init) or [this blog post](http://www.erichynds.com/blog/tips-for-developing-jquery-ui-widgets)

Answer (score 3):

A widget has three phases:

```
+-------+----------------+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Phase | Name           | jQuery Method | Description                                         |  
+-------+----------------+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     1 | Creation       | _create       | First time the widget is applied to an element, it is called.                              |  
|     2 | Initialization | _int          | The _init method is called after _create when the widget is first applied to its elements. |  
|     3 | Destruction    | destroy       | The widget's destroy method is used to detach a widget from an element.                    |  
+-------+----------------+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

*NOTE*: The method names starting with an underscore are meant to be private by convention.

---

So there is a difference between `_create` and `_init`. One is used for creation and the other is used for initialization. Every time you call the widget with no arguments or with options, it will indirectly call `_init` method. Therefore, this can be used to *reset* (re-initialize) a widget or pass it different options.

More details about each phase [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh404085.aspx).