# How to decide between _init and _create in jQuery UI widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-plugins

I think I understand the difference between `_create` and `_init` in widget definitions (see for instance [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982870/jquery-widget-create-or-init)), but I'm still not certain about the *purpose* for the distinction. What sorts of setup tasks go in `_create()` or in `_init()`? What goes wrong if the widget author chooses the wrong one?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

From:

- http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ui-1-8-use-of-init
- http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/tips-for-developing-jquery-ui-widgets/
- http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

> Use `_create` to build and inject
>   markup, bind events, etc. Place
>   default functionality in `_init()`.
>   The dialog widget, for example,
>   provides an `autoOpen` parameter
>   denoting whether or not the dialog
>   should be open once the widget is
>   initialized; a perfect spot for
>   `_init()`!

Also:

> The widget factory automatically fires
>   the `_create()` and `_init()` methods
>   during initialization, in that order. 
>   At first glance it appears that the
>   effort is duplicated, but there is a
>   sight difference between the two. 
>   Because the widget factory protects
>   against multiple instantiations on the
>   same element,  `_create()` will be
>   called a maximum of one time for each
>   widget instance, whereas `_init()` will
>   be called each time the widget is
>   called without arguments...

If the author uses `_init()` when `_create()` should have been coded, the result will be that the code in `_init()` will be executed once per widget instantiation.

Comment: Well, once per *call* to the widget :-) In any case, that second link is invaluable (on this and other issues); dunno how I missed it. Thanks much!

Answer (score 5):

**Short answer** here: 
_create() will be executed when you run your jquery-ui plugin for the first time, like $xx.your-plugin(your options);
_init() will be executed **first and after the first time** when your code runs into $xx.your-plugin(your options);

As there are some code in jquery-ui.custom.js like this:

```
var instance = $.data( this, fullName );
if ( instance ) {
    instance.option( options || {} )._init();
}
```

So, if you **draw a chart** with jquery-ui plugin, after it's drawn out, then you want to **use new data to update it**, you need to do this in _init() to update your chart.
If you just display something and won't update them totally, _create() will meet your needs.